# vue.js - minified css not rendering properly on Azure static site

Tags: javascript, css, azure, vue.js

I've deployed a static vue.js website to Azure: https://surgedemo.z16.web.core.windows.net/

The dev build renders fine in Chrome and Safari on OS X and so does the production build when I serve it from the dist directory.

However, the CSS doesn't seem to be rendered from the website. I've uploaded the files with the correct mime types.

Weirdly, when I use the Chrome Developer Tools to prettify the CSS from the static site, it then renders fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like mimetype is not set correctly:

```
$ curl https://surgedemo.z16.web.core.windows.net/css/app.dc7c3871.css -v 2>&1 | grep Content-Type
< Content-Type: text/plain
```

Review this on azure. From other user experiences there could be some possible points of failure, check this hint:

> Alright, got it. Had to purge my Cdn Endpoint. It has cached my file
>   when it had it's MIME type set to "application/octeet-stream".
>   Basically need to set it to "text/css" and then purge the Endpoint so
>   it gets a fresh version from the storage Account.

source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a65eee29-e021-4d4d-9feb-490f5c89b7ea/troubles-with-azure-cdn-and-css-files?forum=azurecdn

Comment: That's great, thank you! I was using libmagic for mime detection on uploading to Azure and (I now realise) it gets js and css wrong.